# Why SSH does not use a certificate authority in the same way as SSL

Tags: public-key, tls, ssh

SSL requires the use of a trusted third party -- the certificate authority to verify a public key presented by a server to a client.

SSH on the other hand relies on the client having the server's public key by some other means (e.g., by accessing it physically from the server and saving it at the client).

Why do these protocols have such a difference in operation mechanisms? I mean they could both use the third party approach which to me seems more user-friendly and possibly more secure.

Comment: Confirmed cross-post of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126785/why-ssl-uses-a-third-party-certificate-authority-yet-ssh-does-not where it already received two answers at the time of writing this. Note that you’re free to edit this question to clarify why a cross-post makes sense in this case. If there’s a good (read: valid) reason for a cross-post, I’ll gladly reopen this.